# Highly effect find a byte[] is contained by another byte[]

Tags: java, calculator

I want to find a `byte[]` like:

```
010 -000 -100 -000 -003 -030 -001 -000 -065 -099 -116 -135 -118 -101
```

in another `byte[]` with 1024 length. What should I do for that?(For Java)

Comment: `-135` can not be stored in a byte

Comment: stored by cast and become -121